# mongo search with variable names

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to search mongo collection to retrieve some value based on variable name, like this
sportName = "/Basketball/i";

```
db.Team.find({name:sportName}).forEach(function (team) {
    print(team.name);
});
```

It always returns nothing although when I search using the following script it returns result

```
db.Team.find({name: /Basketball/i}).forEach(function (team) {
    print(team.name);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign a regex to a variable like this:

```
sportName = "/Basketball/i";    // This is a string.
```

Do it like this:

```
sportName = /Basketball/i;      // This is a regex.
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found this one to be of good use
{"sportName" : { '$regex' : 'Basketball', $options: '-i' }}